# Redirection to exact URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all addresses to the new domain. One to one, because there is no rule. Instead of redirecting me to:
https://www.new_domain.com/uk/blog/category/news

my rule is redirecting me to:

https://www.new_domain.com/uk/blog/category/newspage/3/.

Please help, I've tried several ways and nothing works.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Redirect 301 /news/page/3/ https://www.new_domain.com/uk/blog/category/news

</IfModule>
```

Comment: try `Redirect /news/page/3/ https://www.new_domain.com/uk/blog/category/news`

Comment: Thanks @Pandurang! It works, but it redirects 302, not 301. Thanks to you I found a solution. `RedirectMatch 301 ^/news/page/3/?$ https://www.new_domain.com/uk/blog/category/news`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below tag and test.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/news/page/3/?$ https://www.new_domain.com/uk/blog/category/news
```